# realloc() in c.. printing junk value

Tags: c, realloc

i have uploaded all of the code.. this is work in progress.. please check for realloc() because if i dont reach the condition for realloc() everything works fine...Thanks evry1..

```
  // contactinfo.h--  header file 
  #ifndef _ELEMENT_H

  #define _ELEMENT_H

  typedef struct ContactInfo ContactInfo;

  struct ContactInfo{
    char Name[30];

    char email_id[50];

    int phon_num;

  };


typedef ContactInfo **ContactList;

 #endif 

 //contactops.h

  #include "contactInfo.h"

ContactList createCL(int size);

void addContact(ContactList clist1, ContactList clist2, ContactInfo ci, int size);

ContactInfo *findByName(ContactList cl, char *name);

ContactInfo *findByNumber(ContactList cl, int num);

void deleteContactByName(ContactList cl, ContactList c2, char *name);

void deleteContactByNumber(ContactList cl, ContactList c2, int num);

void printContacts(ContactList cl);

void Merge_Sort(int hi, int mid, int lo, ContactList c);

void Merge(int hi , int lo, ContactList c);
```

//contactopsarr.c
     #include

```
 #include <string.h>

 #include <stdlib.h>

 #include "contactInfo.h"

 #include "contactOps.h"


int counter =0;                     

int buff_size = 5;                  //pre defined Size

ContactList arr_name;               //to hold the pointers to the locations of 
the shared data by name

ContactList arr_num;                //to hold the pointers to the locations of the shared data by number

ContactInfo *list ;                 // to hold the shared date

int main (){

    char search_name[20];           //buffer to hold the name to be searched

    int search_numb;                //buffer to hold the number to be searched
    arr_num = createCL(buff_size);  

    arr_name = createCL(buff_size);

    /************************* Allocation Of the Shared Data *******************************/

    list = malloc(buff_size * sizeof(ContactInfo));

    if(list == NULL){
        printf("Memmory Allocation Of the shared Data failed..\n");
    }

    /************************ Allocation Completed *****************************************/


    char choice;                    //to hold "y" or "n"

    printf("Do you want to Continue...");

    scanf(" %c",&choice);

    int option;                     //to hold Choice number to be selected
    ContactInfo ci;                 //buffer to hold the information to be added

    while(choice == 'Y'|| choice=='y')
    {
        printf("\n1.Add Contact\n2.FIND Contact by NAME\n3.FIND Contact by NUMBER\n4.DELETE contact by NAME\n5.DELETE contact by NUMBER\n6.PRINT contact\n");
        printf("Enter Your Option..\n");
        scanf(" %d",&option);
        switch(option)
        {
            case 1: printf("Enter the Name:\n");
                    scanf(" %s",&ci.Name);
                    printf("Enter the Number:\n");
                    scanf(" %d",&ci.phon_num);
                    printf("Enter the Email-id:\n");
                    scanf(" %s",&ci.email_id);
                    addContact(arr_num , arr_name, ci, buff_size);
                    break;

        /*  case 2: printf("Enter the name to be Searched..\n");
                    scanf(" %s",&search_name);
                    findByName(list, search_name);
                    break;

            case 3: printf("Enter the number to be Searched..\n");
                    scanf(" %s",&search_numb);
                    findByNumber(list,search_numb );
                    break;

            case 4: break;

            case 5: break;
*/
            case 6: printContacts(arr_num);
                    break;  

            default : printf("Enter a Correct Choice...\n");

        }

    }

}



ContactList createCL(int size){
    ContactList temp = malloc(buff_size * sizeof(ContactInfo *));
    return temp;
}

void addContact(ContactList clist1, ContactList clist2, ContactInfo ci, int size)
{   

    printf("Val of counter : %d\n",counter);
    printf("Val of buff_size : %d\n", size);
    if((counter+1)>=size)
    {
        /*realloc(list, (buff_size +5)*sizeof(ContactInfo ));
        //ContactInfo *temp = malloc((size+5)*sizeof(ContactInfo));
        if(list == NULL){
            printf("Extended Memory Allocation(0) Failed..Quiting..");
            exit(1);
        }
        /*memcpy(temp, list, counter-1);
        list = temp;
        free(temp);*/
        ContactInfo *tmp_list = realloc(list, (buff_size + 5) * sizeof(ContactInfo));
        if (tmp_list == NULL)
        {
            free(list);
            printf("Extended Memory Allocation(0) Failed..Quiting..");
            exit(1);
        }
        list = tmp_list;



        /*realloc(clist1, (size +5)*sizeof(ContactInfo*));
        //ContactList temp1 = malloc((size+5)*sizeof(ContactList));
        if(clist1 == NULL){
            printf("Extended Memory Allocation(1) Failed..Quiting..");
            exit(1);
        }
        /*memcpy(temp1, clist1, counter-1);
        clist1 = temp1;*/
        ContactList tmp_list1 = realloc(clist1, (buff_size + 5) * sizeof(ContactInfo *));
        if (tmp_list1 == NULL)
        {
            free(clist1);
            printf("Extended Memory Allocation(1) Failed..Quiting..");
            exit(1);
        }
        clist1 = tmp_list1;


        /*realloc(clist1, (size +5)*sizeof(ContactInfo*));
        //ContactList temp2 = malloc((size+5)*sizeof(ContactList));
        if(clist2 == NULL){
            printf("Extended Memory Allocation(2) Failed..Quiting..");
            exit(1);
        }
        /*memcpy(temp2, clist2, counter-1);
        clist2 = temp2;
        */
        ContactList tmp_list2 = realloc(clist2, (buff_size + 5) * sizeof(ContactInfo *));
        if (tmp_list2 == NULL)
        {
            free(clist2);
            printf("Extended Memory Allocation(2) Failed..Quiting..");
            exit(1);
        }
        clist2 = tmp_list2;

        buff_size = buff_size + 5;  
    }

    list[counter] = ci;
    clist1[counter] = &list[counter];               //holding the location of the list[counter]..
    clist2[counter] = &list[counter];

    counter = counter + 1;              //updating the counter
}



ContactInfo *findByName(ContactList cl, char *name)
{

}

ContactInfo *findByNumber(ContactList cl, int num)
{


}


/*
void deleteContactByName(ContactList cl, ContactList c2, char *name);
void deleteContactByNumber(ContactList cl, ContactList c2, int num);*/

void printContacts(ContactList cl)
{
    int i ;
    for(i=0 ; i<20; i++)
    {
        printf(" %s\n", cl[i]->Name);
    }
}

void Merge(int hi , int lo, ContactList c)
{
    if(hi>lo)
    {
        int mid = (hi + lo)/2;
        Merge(mid, lo, c);
        Merge(mid+1, hi, c);
        Merge_Sort(hi, mid, lo, c);

    }
}

void Merge_Sort(int hi, int mid, int lo, ContactList c)
{
    ContactList arr1 = malloc(((counter/2)+1)*sizeof(ContactInfo *));
    if(arr1 ==  NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory Allocation(3) failed");
    }

    ContactList arr2 = malloc(((counter/2)+1)*sizeof(ContactInfo *));
    if(arr2 ==  NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory Allocation(4) failed");
    }

    int i, j;
    int limit_first = mid - lo + 1 ;
    int limit_second = hi - mid;

    for(i=0; i<limit_first; i++)
    {
        arr1[i] = c[i];
    }

    for(j=0; j<limit_second; i++)
    {
        arr2[j] = c[mid + j + 1];
    }

    /*ContactInfo temp;
    strcpy(temp.Name , "zzzzzzz");
    temp.phon_num = 99999999999;
    strcpy(temp.email_id, "zzzzzzz");

    arr1[i] = &temp;
    arr1[j] = &temp;*/

    int k;
    i=0;
    j=0;
    for(k=0; k<hi; k++)
    {

        if(arr1[i] >= arr2[j])
        {
            c[k] = arr2[j];
            j++;
        }

        else
        {
            c[k] = arr1[i];
            i++;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: did not solve my problem.. can i mail u my code...because its really bugging me alot...

Comment: Can you post the 'new' non-working code with the answer given below that still doesn't work?

Comment: Think about how to pass your results back to caller. You pass the pointers to your function. You use realloc() which does not guarantees that new pointer will be the same. Think about pointers to pointers as arguments of your function. P.S. note that you realloc clist1 twice...

Comment: Line 10 uses list.  This is not mentioned in the parameters. Neither is buff_size.  Where are these variables defined?

Comment: i have done the editing..please guys hav a look at it..

Comment: anyone guys..!!! need to solve it asap..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error... i did not need to pass (buff_size+5)*sizeof(contactinfo *) but simply realloc(list, buff_size+5);...worked for me...

Answer (score 8):

One problem is that [`realloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) *returns the address* of the newly allocated memory: **store the return value of `realloc()`**. It may allocate a completely new block of memory and copy the content of the memory being realloc'd into and [`free()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) the previous memory. Accessing the previous memory, now `free()`d, is undefined behaviour and is a probable cause of the junk output after reallocation.

Save the return value of `realloc()` to a temporary pointer and update `list` (and the other pointers used in conjunction with `realloc()`) only if non-`NULL` pointer is returned:

```
ContactInfo* tmp_list = realloc(list, (buff_size + 5) * sizeof(ContactInfo));
if (tmp_list == NULL)
{
    free(list);
    fprintf(stderr, "Extended Memory Allocation(0) Failed..Quiting..");
    exit(1);
}
list = tmp_list;
```

Answer (score 0):

*I assume ContactList is a typedef to a struct pointer?*

When you pass in clist1 to this function it contains a pointer to a block in memory.

realloc *possibly* changes this pointer to something else (and moves all the memory contents to this new pointer).

This new value is lost when you exit this function as you passed clist1 as a pointer.

To make sure this works correctly, you need to pass a pointer to a pointer and derefence it during the function.  This makes sure if the pointer changes, the calling function will know about it.

```
void addContact(ContactList* clist1, ContactList clist2, ContactInfo ci, int size)
{
```